# Click Function Conflict in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a handler for the click function to redirect to some link. I have a parent div which has a click handler to redirect to google.com and inside the parent div, I have a subdiv with an anchor tag pointing to yahoo.com. If I click the sub div containing the link to yahoo.com, it currently goes to google.com. How do I overcome this problem?

I have created a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c2XJf/4/). Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
        <a href="http://yahoo.com">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Javascript code:

```
jQuery('.maindiv').click(function() {
    window.open('http://google.com');    
});
```

I want that clicking the parent div should take the user to `google.com` but any link inside the parent div should take the user to the appropriate link.

Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the correct answer below. Upvoting is fine but marking it correct will help future users of the site (as well as me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/c2XJf/23/

Specifically, you need to stop propagation of the click event on the anchor tag like this:

```
$('.subdiv a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and if you want to open the link of the anchor tag in a new tab/window, add a target attribute to your HTML like this:

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_new">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: I'd just go `window.open(this.href)` to keep it generic, but yeah, this is the correct solution.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your info. sorry for the late reply. I tried this code it works perfect. But i want to give it window.open for the parent div itself and not for the sub div in your case i need to give the window.location for the sub div too right !. I want to omit the window.location for the sub div  to perform the function like if i click the href in there to redirect the yahoo.com?

Comment: See my comment in the code. That part is not necessary. I just added it there to have similarity between your handlers. I have updated the fiddle and the code. Isn't this what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery Code:

```
$('.subdiv a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');
});
$('.subdiv').click(function(event){
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');
});
$('.maindiv').click(function(event){
    window.open('http://google.com');
});
```

and you can set width style for subdiv to show redirects perfectly.

Updated code is:
http://jsfiddle.net/c2XJf/22/

Answer (score 1):

check if target div is the current div..

try this

```
jQuery('.maindiv').click(function(e) {
 if(e.target == this){
     window.open('http://google.com');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){window.open('http://yahoo.com');});
```

Comment: This will not prevent the opening of google.com since the event will bubble up to the original handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem simply checking the **tagName** of the clicked element and redirecting to the corresponding page.

```
jQuery('.maindiv').click(function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    //checks if a tag has been clicked or not
    if(!target.is('a')){
        window.open('http://google.com');
    }
    else{
        window.open("http://yahoo.com");
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bLApm/)

Answer (score 1):

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="subdiv">
        <a href="#">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
jQuery('.maindiv').click(function() {
    window.open('http://google.com');    
});
jQuery('.maindiv').find('a').click(function() {
    window.open('http://yahoo.com');    
});
```